# Why is right part being positioned differently in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

On this page:

http://phplist.xxmn.com/node/18

In IE7 and Firefox, the right part (the css class is contentsidebar) displays ok, but in IE6, it doesn't  display well. It is displayed abnormally - the location is at the bottom right.

I know IE6 is dead, but in China, there are lots of people still using it.

How do I correct the CSS to make the page display adequately in IE6? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ugly as sin, but it fixes your IE6 problem:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<style>
#leftcontent {
    width: 660px
}

.bread_nav, #leftcontent .node, #leftcontent h1, #author_info {
    width: auto !important
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

*(You can put this in its own stylesheet if you wish. Make sure it's the last one.)*

The idea is to set the width of `#leftcontent` to a bit less than it was, then override all the million different instances you have of `width: 668px` (these extraneous widths are not needed for any browser, by the way) on elements inside `#leftcontent` to `auto` width.

@Summer had the right idea about changing widths around, she was just missing the specifics.

Comment: thank you,got it,i put the code into the page's <head>...</head> if i want to put it into the site's style.css, how should i do?

Comment: I recommend you just leave it in it's own IE stylesheet called "ie6.css" or similar. Doing that is the conventional way. If you're absolutely certain you want to go against the normal way - you can use a CSS hack to serve styles to only IE6. Perhaps the [Star HTML Hack](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Star_Html_Hack)? So at the bottom of your `style.css` you would put for example `* html #leftcontent { width: 660px }` and `* html .bread_nav, * html  #leftcontent .node ..` . I don't recommend that though.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a width issue to me.  IE6 thinks the right sidebar is too wide, and so it moves the content box to below the previous float (i.e. below the main content).  The div class="contentsidebar" has a width of 300 - try changing it to 295px or 290px and see if that fixes the issue.